# Does the failbit effect the call ignore on cin?

Tags: c++, ios, cin

After a failbit is set:
When I first call cin.clear() and then cin.ignore(), the programe is right.
And when I first call cin.ignore() and then cin.clear(), the ignore seems to not work, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin.clear()` clears the failbit, but `cin.ignore()` doesn't.

it means that, if the stream is in an invalid state, calling `clear()` followed by `ignore()` will reset the state to good, then ignore the next character.

On the other hand, calling `ignore()` followed by `clear()` means `ignore()` will fail, then `clear()` will proceed to reset the stream state. So, in that case, the next character will not be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

`cin.ignore()` only does its work of consuming data from the stream if `cin.good()` is `true`. If the `failbit` is set, then `cin.good()` will be `false`.