# C++ std::cout not writing anything to the console

Tags: c++

Forgive me for my noobishness as I have only just begun learning C++, but I came across something that's confusing me. The following code is me following along the examples from the C++ Primer 5th Edition PDF found [here](http://breezeflutter.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/c_primer_5th_edition.pdf).

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int sum = 0, value = 0;
    while (std::cin >> value)
        sum += value;
    std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl; //this doesn't do anything
    std::cin.ignore().get();
    return 0;
}
```

Now for some reason, the last `std::cout` statement doesn't do anything at all, and it's perplexing me as aside from the `std::cin.ignore().get()` this is the exact same as the example in the pdf and yet this doesn't do anything. What confuses me the most is that if I write `value` from inside the while loop you can observe that it doesn't recur infinitely; it stops like it should after the last input value, so the error shouldn't be in the execution of the while loop.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

EDIT2: The input I'm using is `3 4 5 6`

EDIT3: For comparison's sake, here is the code from C++ Primer 5th Edition:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
     int sum = 0, value = 0;
     // read until end-of-file, calculating a running total of all values read
     while (std::cin >> value)
         sum += value; // equivalent to sum = sum + value
     std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl; return 0;
}
```

So the **ONLY** difference between mine and this is the `std::cin.ignore().get()`.

Comment: Is this your entire code? Is there anything else happening *before* the while loop?

Comment: Worked for me .. http://ideone.com/R7ItHq

Comment: That is the entirety of the code. Also, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, could that be affecting it?

Comment: what are you providing for standard input?

Comment: `3 4 5 6` is the input I'm using.

Comment: @user3002473 This can not be the full input. The program would expect another number after the last one and wait for it infinitely.

Comment: @Nabla:That `std::cin.ignore().get();` is just so that the console doesn't immediately close upon execution. Also, it may be useful to note that if I remove that line, the console doesn't immediately close, meaning it doesn't even reach that part of the code.

Comment: did you hit Ctrl+C to stop inputting values?

Comment: Are you providing an invalid entry to end the loop? Are you sure the program is terminating? Try entering `1 2 3 4 a`.

Comment: Entering `1 2 3 4 a` in seemed to yield the proper results, but now for some reason it's completely skipping over the `std::cin.ignore().get();`, exiting the application before I get a chance to see what the output really is.

Comment: You have to clear the stream first: `std::cin.clear()`

Comment: At what condition exactly do you want the loop to terminate ?

Comment: By default it terminates when it encounters either a non-integer input or an `EOF` error as Pinepara said, which is what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`while (std::cin >> value)` means it will not stop until failed to read an integer, i.e encountering an `EOF` or a non-integer input.

On Windows, use ^Z (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) to enter an `EOF`.

Try input:

```
1 2 3 4
^Z
```

It should hit the cout line. And it's totally a different question about the `cin.ignore()` stuff.

Comment: @Nabla Yep, you're right. He's inputing '3 4 5 6', which I think might be the problem.

Comment: Interesting. When I input `3 4 5 6 ^Z`, it didn't even hit the `std::cin.ignore().get()`, it closed immediately.

Comment: @user3002473 Use `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); std::cin.get()`.

Comment: I think it actually hit that line. Maybe you could try setting a breakpoint to make sure.

Comment: @0x499602D2 that didn't do anything, and I'd prefer to stay out of the realm of things I don't understand for now so as to not confuse myself to early into learning C++.

Comment: @user3002473 `cin.ignore` doesn't do anything if a previous extract failed. This is the case here as your while loop depends on one failing input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002747/does-the-failbit-effect-the-call-ignore-on-cin You need to call `cin.clear()` first.

Comment: @user3002473 You have to clear the stream state first using `std::cin.clear()`, then a call to `.ignore()` and `.get()` will work.

Comment: It still didn't do anything! How could this problem have such an elusive answer?

Comment: @user3002473 0x499602D2's version of `std::ignore` discards an unlimited number of characters until `'\n'` is encountered (assuming the stream is in the `good` state). Your call to  will only ignore a single character, it's (essentially) equivalent to `cin.ignore(1, '\n');`. Did you add the call to `std::clear()` like several people suggested?

Comment: @user3002473 What do you mean by 'do anything'? It should help you hit the cout line. If the program exits immediately, you may wanna try it in a cmd or use breakpoint to pause anywhere you want to.

Comment: I did indeed try that out and there was no difference, no output at all.

Comment: @Pinepara I meant that it still didn't write anything to the console, nothing happened after I input `3 4 5 6` or `3 4 5 6 a` or `3 4 5 6 ^Z`. Could it be something unrelated to the code, having to do with the settings on my Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: @user3002473 By 'nothing happened' do you mean the program is still waiting for input or quit immediately? By the way, did you hit `Enter` and the end of input?

Comment: @Pinepara, 'nothing happened' meant that it was still waiting for input. But after shifting around the positions of `std::cin.clear()` and 0x499602D2's version of `std::ignore` it works only if I input `3 4 5 6 a` or `3 4 5 6 ^Z`. Why on earth would it work in such a simple, easily understandable manner in the example code presented by the pdf, yet only work in such a convoluted way here?

Comment: And thank you to everyone who helped solve this! I definitely wasn't expecting my first day with C++ to go like this...